# Spark Delta Table Add new columns in middle Schema Evolution

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Have to ingest a file with new column into a existing table structure.

```
create table sch.test (
name string ,
address string 
) USING DELTA 
--OPTIONS ('mergeSchema' 'true')
PARTITIONED BY (name)
LOCATION  '/mnt/loc/fold'
TBLPROPERTIES (delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite = true, delta.autoOptimize.autoCompact = true);
```

Code to read the file:
val df = spark.read
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.load("/mnt/loc/fold")

```
display(df)
```

File in path contains below data

```
name,address
raghu,india
raj,usa
```

On writing it to a table,

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("az_insert_ts", current_timestamp())
.withColumn("exec_run_id",lit("233"))
.withColumn("az_inp_file_name",lit("24234filename"))
     .coalesce(12)
     .write
     .mode("append")
     .option("mergeSchema", "true")
     .format("delta")
     .saveAsTable("sch.test")
display(spark.read.table("sch.test"))
```

[image]

Adding a new column,

```
name,address,age
raghu,india,12
raj,usa,13
```

Read the file,

```
    val df = spark.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header", "true")
        .load("/mnt/loc/fold")

display(df)
```

While writing into the table using insertInto,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("az_insert_ts", current_timestamp())
.withColumn("exec_run_id",lit("233"))
.withColumn("az_inp_file_name",lit("24234filename"))
     .coalesce(12)
     .write
     .mode("append")
     .option("mergeSchema", "true")
     .format("delta")
     .insertInto("sch.test")
display(spark.read.table("sch.test"))
```

Getting the below error,

[image]

Comment: From what I know the databricks tables are immutable. So there really isn't any way to do this. You need to delete the old table and create a new one with a new schema.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `overwriteSchema` to `true` will wipe out the old schema and let you create a completely new table.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn(""az_insert_ts"", current_timestamp())
.withColumn(""exec_run_id"",lit(""233""))
.withColumn(""az_inp_file_name"",lit(""24234filename""))
     .coalesce(12)
     .write
     .mode(""append"")
     .option(""overwriteSchema"", ""true"")
     .format(""delta"")
     .insertInto(""sch.test"")
display(spark.read.table(""sch.test""))
```

Comment: will it wipe out the data as well?